# How do I use Autofac instead singleton in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, singleton, autofac

I have used singleton pattern a using static property, constructor

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private readonly MemoryCacheManager _cacheManager;
    private static readonly Lazy<MyClass> _Lazy = new Lazy<MyClass>(() => new MyClass());
    public static MyClass Language { get { return _Lazy.Value; } }

    private MyClass()
    {
        _cacheManager = new MemoryCacheManager();          
        LoadCacheData();
    }

    // Rest of class
}
```

I have tried like following using Autofac in `global.asax`:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
     builder.RegisterType<MemoryCacheManager>().SingleInstance(); 
 }
```

And inside `MyClass` constructor:

```
private MyClass(MemoryCacheManager cache)
{
    _cacheManager = cache;
    LoadCacheData();
}

public string Translate(string language)
{   
    var translation = _cacheManager.GetValueFromCache();
}
```

And I want to call this method in `Index.cshtml`

Previously I did it directly like this:

```
<h4>@MyClass.Language.Translate("Welcome", Model.Language)</h4>
```

As I had `Language` as follow in `MyClass`:

```
public static Localizer Language { get { return _Lazy.Value; } }
```

But now I do not have this property.

> How can I call Translate method in Index.cshtml as I do not have static property like previous.

Comment: There's multiple examples in their doc.

Comment: stills as a newbie its little confusing , so can you give me specific thread related to my implementation , it will be great help :) thanks

Comment: In your `Application_Start` are you also setting the `DependencyResolver`? And I assume that `Translate` should have a return statement in place of the assignment?

Comment: I have not set DependencyResolver . I do not have any idea :(
Translate method will return a string translator value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to register `MyClass` as a `SingleInstance` with your container:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>().SingleInstance();
```

Then inject where ever you need:

```
public AnotherClass(IMyClass myClass)
{
     _myClass = myClass;
}
```

Although it's probably the cache you want a single instance of. In that case:

```
builder.RegisterType<MemoryCacheManager>().SingleInstance();
```

And then:

```
public MyClass(MemoryCacheManager cache)
{
    _cacheManager = cache;          
    LoadCacheData();
}
```

**EDIT:**

The first thing you need to do is set the `DependencyResolver` in your `Application_Start` class (you'll need to get the [Autofac MVC Integration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/) NuGet package for this):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    this.RegisterAutoFac();

    // Rest of method
}

private void RegisterAutoFac()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

    builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>();
    builder.RegisterType<MyCache>().As<IMyCache>().SingleInstance();

    var container = builder.Build();

    // Setup the dependency resolver
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

Then you need to inject `MyClass` into the constructor of your controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyClass _myClass;

    public TestController(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
    }

    // Rest of the controller
}
```

Then when your creating model for you get the data you need from `MyClass`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ExampleModel 
        { 
            WelcomeMessage = _myClass.Translate("Welcome") 
        };

    return View(model);
}
```

And in your view:

```
<h4>@Model.WelcomeMessage</h4>
```

Comment: @RagtimeWily where exactly I need to register MyClass as a SingleInstance? in MyClass itself (in MyClass Constructor) ? or where please guide thanks

Comment: I'm assuming this is an asp.net app based on tag. You should build container as part of the Application_Start and then call `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));`.

Comment: I'm using this code in a separate class library project

Comment: Even if the code is in a separate assembly the registration still needs to be done as part of the start up of the application that will be calling the code.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I tried the same but stuck at Index.cshtml Translate method as there is no static property now :( can you help me in this?

Comment: @ashish I updated the answer to try to give more detail on some of the issues you seem to be having trouble with.

Comment: thanks but in my case what should I put inside IMyClass interface? please guide also currently i'm setting more values to model   UserProfileModel userModel = new UserProfileModel();
            userModel.Language = languageCode;
            userModel.UserName = userName;

            return View("About", userModel);

Comment: It should contain whatever behaviours or operations implemented classes will have. In the example I gave just a `string Translate(string s);` method

Comment: ok and what about this previous code `  //private MyClass(MemoryCacheManager cache)
        //{
        //    _cacheManager = cache;

        //    // timer - loadcache method call
     //LoadCacheData();
        //}` we take care this in Global,asax now is it

Comment: is there any generic general solution to all this ?

Comment: If you need to pre-load cache it's up to you where you do it. I can't really offer advice as I don't know anything about the application.

Comment: I missed again something getting error :
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Client.MyClass' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Client.MemoryCacheManager cache' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Client.MemoryCacheManager)'.

Comment: Sounds like `MemoryCacheManager` hasn't been registered with container correctly. Remember, if you register `.As<IMyCache>()` your `MyClass` needs to accept `ICache` in the constructor - not the concrete type.

Comment: I have used only EDIT code not first one. only this one  `builder.RegisterType<Localizer>().As<ILocalizer>();
            builder.RegisterType<Localizer>().As<ILocalizer>().SingleInstance();`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think you may need to read up on Dependency Injection in general.

Comment: true i'm doing that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73061/discussion-between-ragtimewilly-and-ashish).